# nfs-server won't start on readonly mounted root

Tags: nfs

Systemctl doesn`t tell specific details and lsof will not give any clue ...

/etc/fstab:

```
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nosuid,size=300m            0 0
tmpfs           /var/tmp        tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nosuid,size=50m             0 0
tmpfs           /var/log        tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nosuid,mode=0755,size=100m  0 0
tmpfs           /var/run        tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nosuid,mode=0755,size=5m    0 0
tmpfs           /root           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nosuid,size=10m             0 0
/dev/mmcblk2p1  /boot           ext2    defaults,ro                                  0 0
/dev/mmcblk2p2  /               f2fs    defaults,ro                                  0 0
/dev/mmcblk2p3  /mnt/data       f2fs    defaults,noatime,discard                     0 0
```

any idea?

Greets ... Peedy

Comment: `roofs`? I seem to remember *root*, *mounting point* - care to mention a/the operating environment?

Comment: OK, little mistake ... corrected yet ... tnx ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Check errors:

```
sudo systemctl status nfs-server.service
```

I have had these error messages:

```
exportfs[432]: exportfs: could not open /var/lib/nfs/.etab.lock for locking: errno 30 (Read-only file system)


exportfs[433]: exportfs: can't open /var/lib/nfs/etab.tmp for writing
```

These console commands helped me:

```
touch /tmp/.etab.lock
sudo ln -s /tmp/.etab.lock /var/lib/nfs/.etab.lock
touch /tmp/etab.tmp
sudo ln -s /tmp/etab.tmp /var/lib/nfs/etab.tmp
```

And restart service or system.